# In a django app, how do I prevent users from deleting content not created by them?

Tags: python, django, authentication, view, web-development-server

I have created a simple question apps, when clicked on questions it shows its options or choices.I made login and signup forms to make user-login.

I want to know how can I limit the user to delete the questions created only by them.Every question has a delete key infront of it.

I read most stuff about permissions but didnt got it how to do it.

I may apply permission not to delete any question but how to restrict a user not to delete only some specific questions or questions that weren't created by them.
below is views.py

```
def addquestion(request):
    item_to_add = request.POST['content']
    item = Question.objects.create(question_text=item_to_add,pub_date=timezone.now())
    user_now = Question(user = request.user)
    item.save()

    return HttpResponseRedirect('/home/questions')


def deletequestion(request,question_id):

    item_to_delete = Question.objects.get(id=question_id)
    if item_to_delete.user == request.user:
        item_to_delete.delete()
    else:
    return HttpResponse('You are not authorised to delete this question')
```

Here is models .py

```
from django.db import models
from vote.models import VoteModel
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.
class Question(VoteModel,models.Model):

    question_text = models.TextField(max_length=300)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete = models.CASCADE,null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text

class Choice(models.Model):
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question,on_delete = models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should filter your questions queryset:

```
from django.db.models import Q
...
try:
    Question.objects.get(Q(id=question_id)&Q(user=request.user)).delete()
except Question.DoesNotExist:
    raise PermissionDenied("User can't delete this question.")
...
```

The Q object allows you to logically operate with filters.

Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/2.1/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects

Update:
As pointed out in comments, in this particular case you can achieve this by doing the following:

```
try:
    Question.objects.get(id=question_id, user=request.user).delete()
except Question.DoesNotExist:
    raise PermissionDenied("User can't delete this question.")
```

Comment: `get(Q(id=question_id)&Q(user=request.user))` is the same as `get(id=question_id, user=request.user)`, just longer

Comment: Into the deletequestion view , I did what u explained , I am creating a question , its also appearing on the question page , But when I click on delete option, its responding a permission denied error even though that question was created by me.

Comment: I did and it worked but the problem is when i set the user field to user instance , it dont let me create multiple questions , i can only created one question.

Comment: that is because you use a OneToOneField, change it to a ForeignKeyField

Comment: `item = Question.objects.create(question_text=item_to_add,pub_date=timezone.now(),user = request.user)`

Comment: do you have something like this?    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True) and the applied the migrations?

Comment: Ok ok ok , thanks a lot Juan , It helped a lot , i forgot to apply migrations after changing it to foreign key.Thanks for you time. Can you tell me some source to learn advanced django after i complete basics.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe request.user is a string that contains the id of the user so you will have to get the user object of that id before comparing it with  item_to_dele.user.

```
logged_user = User.objects.get(id=request.user)
if logged_user == item_to_delete.user:
    # delete
    item_to_delete.delete()
else:
    return HttpResponse('You are not authorised to delete this question')
```

Comment: `request.user` should already be a `User` object: there's no need for `User.objects.get(id=request.user)` (unless the authentication system has been customized). Also, it'd be better to raise a `PermissionDenied`, so that the user will get a 401 response instead of 200